# In C + + singleton mode, if I modify a member variable in two member functions, will it conflict？

Tags: c++

In C + + singleton mode, if I modify a  member variable in two member functions, will it conflict?Do I need a mutex?

for example:

```
class Teacher
{
     int var;
     int func1(int a)
     {
         var = a;
     }
     int func2(int b)
     {
         var = b;
     }
     ...
}
```

what is "singleton mode" in c++? I define a class to explain this question.The purpose is to make the whole program have only one object of this class.
for example:

```
class terminal485{
public:    
    ~terminal485();
    terminal485(const terminal485&)=delete;
    terminal485& operator=(const terminal485&)=delete;
    static terminal485& Instance(){
        static terminal485 instance;
        return instance;
    }
    void setPointer(AxesGroupRef *axes){
        if(axes != nullptr && this->p_axes == nullptr){
            this->p_axes = axes;            
            printf("[%s] %p\n",__FUNCTION__,axes);
        }
    }    

    int recvTerminal485Message(char *readbuf);
    int getIndex();
    int getBuf(char *readbuf);
private:
    terminal485():p_axes(nullptr), m_bufLen(0){
        printf("[%s] construct this class \n\n\n\n\n",__FUNCTION__);
    }
    AxesGroupRef *p_axes;
    Terminal485Protocol m_protocol;
    char m_recvBuf[200];
    int m_bufLen;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
};
```

Comment: What is "singleton mode"?

Comment: I depends on whether these two methods are called concurrently or not. If they are not run concurrently, then no and you don't need a mutex. If they are run concurrently, you'd better declare `var` as volatile.

Comment: Yes you need a mutex for any member that could be acessed from two different threads.  Doesn't matter if it's two different functions or the same function.

Comment: @MarkRansom: There's no footprint of threading in this code.

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder good point, but there's *never* a need to consider mutexes unless you have multi threading.

Comment: @MarkRansom: true, but actually the operation is atomic (thread-safe) so a mutex would not be useful. When the value is changed what may happen is that a caching may take place so that two different values would be observed by two different threads, so instead of a mutex marking the variable as volatile would be useful.

Comment: I guess OP said "singleton mode" because in Chinese "singleton pattern" is called as 单例模式, and 模式 is often translated as "mode" rather than "pattern"

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder FYI: [Is volatile useful with threads?](http://isvolatileusefulwiththreads.com/)

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder ```volatile``` has nothing to do with synchronization in C++.

Comment: @frozenca: Completely true, it has something to do with compiler's optimization and that is what I am talking about if you pay attention to my comment.

Comment: @frozenca yes. You are right.

Comment: thread safe and singleton pattern are two things. I can't understand your question.

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder: *"but actually the operation is atomic"* Even if architecture does integer change atomically, it is not true from C++ point of view (so race condition might happen). `std::atomic<int>` (or `std::mutex` or other synchronization way) would be needed.

Comment: @Jarod42: Well, how exactly would that be possible. When you reassign the value of an `int` all threads should instantaneously observe the same value unless the compiler has cached it in CPU register. On the other hand, multiple threads mutating the value of an `int` at the same time does not cause any concurrency exceptions so that means it is also thread-safe. I read the link regarding if Volatile is useful, I still think it is useful because C++ has many compilers and the volatile mechanism has to be compiler specific.

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder: Race-condition is UB (and seems to works is possible outcome, but no changes, or corrupted changes are other possibilities). For atomic operation there is `std::atomic`, `volatile` has nothing to do with multithreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: 'Singleton' is a design pattern, not a 'mode'. (Personally I prefer using a namespace and static variables in the compile unit to represent 'only one instance', but that's a matter of taste).

Regarding your actual questions, unless threads (or interrupts) are involved, all accesses are sequential, which means that it is impossible for the two methods to access the shared variable at the same time, making the behaviour perfectly well defined.

Of course calling either will always overwrite whatever the other method may have done to the variable, changing the state of the object, but this is intended behaviour.

As such: No, there is no 'conflicts' or even 'undefined behaviour' in this scenario. Whether the code will do what you intend it to do however I cannot say.

Assuming you are to incorporate threads, you need to pay better attention, because multiple threads may access the resource concurrently (for example thread A could read the variable, while thread B writes to it, leading to 'A' getting garbage values). This can also happen if there is only one accessor to the internal variable.

To avoid this from happening either:

1. Declare/Ensure that your access is 'atomic' (for C++11 and beyond there's a family of classes that ensure that for you)
2. Use a mutex to protect access.

Comment: Thank you and everyone. I originally thought that the singleton pattern did not consider multithreading，So I'm not sure if I need to add a mutex.

Comment: That fully depends on whether your program is multithreaded at all and, if it is, whether your second thread does access the object at all. From what you've posted, this is about impossible to tell.